# How to dynamically add/remove UI_Elements to the sidebar based on the currently visible page in a Quarto dashboard

Tags: r, dashboard, quarto

I am building a Dashboard with R and Quarto. The Dashboard has several pages (denoted by Level1-Headings #), and a global sidebar (#  {.sidebar}).

The sidebar mainly shows UI-Elements relevant for all pages, however there is one page where I would like to add an additional UI-Element (selectInput) in the sidebar when it is shown.

How can I achieve this? I would like to use renderUI, however I do not know how to identify the currently active page.

I tried to identify the active page with input$navbar (a wild guess), didn't work.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code?